# <a> inside <li> won't link to page, but will work with anchor

Tags: html, css

All my anchor links work fine, however in the second ul a href="page1" will not work. It shows the correct destination in the bottom left of my screen, as well it works on right click -> open in new tab, but not when I click it.

Removing the `<li></li>` around the link makes it work. Any suggestions?

```
 <div class="navmenu">
        <?php if (is_front_page()) { ?>
        <ul class="pull-left">
            <li><a href="#app">app</a></li>
            <li><a href="#why">why</a></li>
            <li><a href="#habits">habits</a></li>
            <li><a href="#faq">faq</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <?php } ?>
        <div class="nav-links pull-right">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="page1">our app</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">the device</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.navmenu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color:#17607D;
}
.navmenu a.pull-left img {
  position:absolute;
}
.navmenu li {
  display: inline-block !important;
  margin-right: 15px;
  line-height: 40px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.navmenu ul {text-align:center;line-height:60px}
.navmenu img {
  margin-top:4px;
  margin-left:6px;
}
.navmenu li a {
  font-size: 23px;
  color:#51c4d4;
  letter-spacing:1px;
  font-family:'EdmondSans', helvetica,sans-serif;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.navmenu li a:hover {
  color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: AFAIK, In php, the `if` statement is closed using `endif`. it is just a guess.

Comment: @Mr_Green Nah, that's when you declare your conditional like `if ($a == 5):` but when you declare it with `if ($a == 5){` that syntax is correctomundo.

Comment: @Jordan, Do you have an online example? Sounds kind of like it could be a JavaScript thing or something else stealing the click event.

Comment: That is absolutely what it was. Thank you! I feel like an absolute dunce now though. If you want to add that as an answer I can select it. Thanks again!

Comment: This is why SE is great. Sometimes you're too close to the answer to see the forest for the trees. :{D

Answer (score 0):

You should use `<a name="contact">` instead of `<a href="#contact">`